# Best strategy for providing theme options using customizer

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, widgets, sidebar

I am making a free distributable theme and I wish I could provide theme options in the best possible way. I have doubts (mostly about widgets) and sidebars. Here we go:

1. Is it a good idea letting the user customize every builtin widget in every possible sidebar, individually ?
2. Or Should I provide Header, Content area and footer wide color / Design options.
3. Or should I provide builtin color options such as dark and light background and color options and leaving widget customization all together?

I don't want to scare users by providing any unnessary options.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal view if I am the theme user. I would say it depends on the theme features

**If it's a one page theme?**

I will like to have all the options in the customizer window.

**If it's a niche/app based theme?**

I will just use the customizer for basic options and setup all the other options in my very Theme options panel in Admin Area.

Comment: In my view, Since I have worked with both types of theme options for extensive amount of time, I strongly recommend using theme customizer for all the possible options. With 4.0, Customizer is now even more powerful with context based options and some advanced controls.

Comment: Question is, How to let user customize widgets with great flexibility and with out disturbing the standards.